# refresh chat <div> every time a new message is inserted into DB(MySQL)

Tags: javascript, php

I have been searching on the net for a code that refreshes the chat `<div>` every time a new message is received from the other chat user. I have read about `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` however need more experienced developers advice and help.

The best example is this website. Unless you refresh the browser, you will not see the notification right away. I guess the best example is facebook. Whenever the Database is updated, the notification is popped up right away without refreshing the browser.

Here`s my code.

```
$check_sql = ("SELECT time from messages where conversation_id = '".$con_id."' ");
$check_query = mysqli_query($con, $check_sql) or die ("ERROR　checking:".mysqli_error($con);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_query){
  $current_time = date_default_timezone_get();
  $message_time_sent = $row['time'];
  $cal = $message_time_sent->diff($current_time);
  $ans = $cal->format("%D %H:%i:%s");
  sscanf($ans,"%d %d:%d:%d ", $day, $hr, $min, $sec);

  if (($day == 0) && ($hr == 0) && ($min == 0) && ($sec >0)){
   //do something here to get receive message automatically and notification....
 }
```

What I want to achieve:

1. Facebook automatically receives messages without refreshing the browser. I hope it could be like this.
2. Automatic pop up of notification without refreshing the browser which I think it is not really important, once we can figure out item 1, then the rest will be all good.

The tricky part about using `setInteval()` the browser will keep refreshing the `<div>` chat so when the user input a text to send, it will disappear everytime it refreshes. Please excuse my English....

So, is there a proper way of handling this....

Comment: You are right. This can be done with `setInterval()`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setInterval** - set interval will call your function every interval you set

setInterval sample: https://repl.it/OE1o

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="sample">
        Day Mon DD YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT+XXX (Time Zone)
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var sample = document.getElementById('sample');
setInterval(
    // Here is where to do things like dom manipulation
    function() {
        sample.innerHTML = new Date;
    },

    // Here is where you set the interval asuming I want to update every 1 second
    1000
);
</script>
```

**setTimeout** - will be call once the timeout is reached.

setTimeout sample: https://repl.it/OE3H

```
setTimeout(
    // This function will be called once the timeout is reached
    function() {
        console.log('Hello World');
    },

    // The timeout is 5 seconds
    5000
);
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, I can see its working, how can I directly specifically to my chat div section only and not affect the whole webpage. Please advice. Even this stackoverflow page do not have it. I have to refresh the webpage inorder to see the new notification. please advice.

Comment: take a look at the first example (setInterval) I have set the attribute of div id="sample" and manipulate it by document.getElementById. Adding id or class to your div will do.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have set it to my chat div, however please help me `chatdiv.innerHTML = new Date;` I think is my problem. instead of the date, how can I set it to update my chat messages. Please advice.

Comment: You need to do some ajax request to get data from your server. Maybe it's a good idea to create another post if you don't know how to do ajax request with javascript or just search if that question is already asked.

Comment: Mark believe me I am not really familiar with ajax. But if I understand, I call them using php from the server.

Comment: What php does is provide a data from your database, AJAX will get data from it and populate your html, AJAX is done in javascript. Voting up will makes me happy :)

Comment: Sorry I have the chat already set up with .... I call all messages according to the conversation id... everything looks great its just that when the other user you chat with sends a message, on my end, chat doest update unless I refresh the browser....

Comment: you have to convert your html into ajax based. search "long polling ajax" it might help you. you may need to modify a little in your code to accomplish it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I finally figure out how to use ajax